# Fetch highest ID from database via Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

After trying a lot of howto's on Google I am still without answers.

I want to fetch an object from the database which has the highest ID (ai).
I know this must be very simple to do, but I couldn't find the solution.

In the database I have the entities **Syncs** which have an auto-increment ID.
I need that (latest) object to retrieve the value `<end>` which is a DateTime.

(It is in Symfony via Doctrine by the way.)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `MAX` function and fetch a single scalar result:

```
$highest_id = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('MAX(e.id)')
    ->from('YourBundle:Entity', 'e')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

To fetch the last object you may just do the following:

```
$last_entity = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('e')
    ->from('YourBundle:Entity', 'e')
    ->orderBy('e.id', 'DESC')
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Comment: Now I get a FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function createQueryBuilder() on a non-object _(first line)_

Comment: @MarcelvanderHorst If you are in your controller, do you have `$em` defined as `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()`?

Comment: I do have a protected function like that `protected function GetEntityManager()
    {
        if ($this->em == null) {
            $this->em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        }
        return $this->em;
    }`

Comment: `$em->getRepository('YourBundle:Entity')->createQueryBuilder('e')->select('MAX(e.id)')->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();`

Comment: Guys, you dont write querries in controllers, come on! Make Repository classes.